# How to retrieve the elements in list without using foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list

How can I retrieve the elements from a list without using a foreach loop?

Comment: I'd like to know why you don't want to use foreach. It might reveal a detail that would help us answer your question better.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why can't you use foreach? What about the list indexer?

Comment: i like to retrieve using iterator

Comment: The concept behind foreach (Enumerators) is the same as iterators. You shouldn't try to avoid it.

Comment: The Way to use iterator is foreach. That actually gets compiles into a call to GetEnumerator() and a loop using that enumerator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{
    var element = list[i];
}
```

or

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var element = enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

You say list, but you don't specify the `List<T>` class as [this answer assumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270575/how-to-retrieve-the-elements-in-list-without-using-foreach-in-c/2270586#2270586) (also, it might be added that that answer uses the Count() extension method.  Since you know the type is of `List<T>` it's better to use the Count *property*).

If you are always working with the `IList<T>` interface implementation, then using a for loop that iterates an index and then accesses the indexer with that value will work fine.

However, if you are dealing with `IEnumerable<T>` implementations, that will not always work.  Rather, you have to do the following:

```
// Get the IEnumerator<T> from the list.
IEnumerator<T> enumerator = list.GetEnumerable();

// Dispose if necessary.
using (enumerator as IDisposable)
{
    // Cycle while there are items.
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Work with enumerator.Current here.
    }
}
```

This is how the compiler expands the foreach statement when it is compiled.  Basically, since `IEnumerable<T>` implementations can implement IDisposable, it prepares for that eventuality by trying to cast to IDisposable.  If it cannot, then the using statement just doesn't do anything on exit.

When using foreach on arrays, the compiler will expand to a loop which accesses the items by index (assuming you are working with an array instance directly), not the enumerator approach above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to avoid this type of loop:

```
 foreach(var item in list) {};
```

...then you can use Linq or Lambda expressions to search and retrieve from the list.

For example:

```
  using System.Linq;

  // ... with Lambda
  var ints = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
  var evenInts = ints.ForEach(i => i % 2 == 0);

  // with straight Linq-to-objects:
  var oddInts = from i in ints
      where i % 2 == 1
      select i;
```